# How do I get a function that uses Tkinter 8.5 to return the selected file from a file dialog box

Tags: tkinter

I would like `fileName` in `vendorFunction()` to obtain the user's input in the Entry box after the user clicks the Format Button. I am newbie and can't figure out how to do this. Below is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def createVendorWindow():
    def browse():
        fileSelected = filedialog.askopenfilename()
        guiInputFileEntry.insert(0, fileSelected)

    def format(file):
        return file

    vendorWindow = Tk()
    vendorWindow.title("Cost Load Converter")

    vendorWindowFrame = ttk.Frame(vendorWindow, padding="12 12 7 7")
    vendorWindowFrame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
    vendorWindowFrame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    vendorWindowFrame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    guiInputFile = StringVar()

    guiInputFileEntry = ttk.Entry(vendorWindowFrame, width=100, textvariable=guiInputFile)
    guiInputFileEntry.grid(column=1, row=1, stick=(W,E))

    ttk.Label(vendorWindowFrame, text="\nPlease enter the full filepath of the file you wish to format:").grid(column=1, row=0)

    browseButton = ttk.Button(vendorWindowFrame, text="Browse...", underline=0, command=browse)
    browseButton.grid(column=2, row=1, padx=5)

    formatButton = ttk.Button(vendorWindowFrame, text="Format", underline=0, command= lambda: format(guiInputFileEntry.get()))
    formatButton.grid(column=1, row=2, pady=5)

    vendorWindow.mainloop()    

def vendorFunction():
    fileName = createVendorWindow()
    print("fileName: ", fileName)
    #then, do stuff with fileName

vendorFunction()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your `format` function returns the filename, but you want your `createVendorWindow` function to return the filename. So you should put `return guiInputFile.get()` behind the `vendorWindow.mainloop()`. Then all the format button needs to do is close the window: `command=lambda: vendorWindow.destroy()`. This stops the mainloop and starts executing everything that is behind the mainloop.